# (Wordpress Avada Theme) Anchor links not working on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, anchor, responsive

I'm building a website for a client in Wordpress using the Avada Theme and for some reason, my nav bar anchor links are not working at all on mobile (when I click on one of the items in the dropdown either using Firefox's responsive view or my actual phone, it just goes to the top of that page, not to the section where the ID is), even though it works fine on desktop.

This is the website in question: http://harcourt.epicdev.co.za/

It's the items under What We Offer that I'm trying to get to work, and unfortunately the Avada forums are no help whatsoever.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in avada you need to add an element *anchor* to the position where it should scroll to and give it a name.
Avada have this ability so you can adjust the exact position of an anchor accordingly to your needs. simply add the anchor element into your page wherever it should scroll to on click in menu, and its done. works in every browser. even IE.
i use the same procedure in my [crypto lexikon](https://news-krypto.de/das-grosse-krypto-lexikon/).